# Put my class into other people's package to access package visible methods?

Tags: java, package, access-modifiers

I undeerstand it's certainly not a good practice, but does Java provide any mechanism to **prevent** accessing package-private methods/attributes? If not, does that mean this:

```
package com.other_people_other_company;

public class MyClass {
  // Let's hack! Access all package privates
}
```

is valid?

## Edit:

It's mentioned in the answer:

```
Name: myCompany/myPackage/
Sealed: true
```

This is new info to me. But what if I sabotage by distributing a jar of mine, and sealing other people's package there? E.g. `Name: org.apache Sealed: true`

Comment: Did you try, are you able to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's true. On this idea some kind of "patch" method is based: when you have to fix some bug in 3d-party library you can create same package with same class in your classpath and create fixed class.

The only one restriction is special package names like `java.util`, e.g. this example will be successfully compiled, though `java.util.Tripwire` class has  package local access modifier:

```
package java.util;

public class TestTripwire {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Tripwire.trip(Object.class, "sss");
    }
}
```

But if you run it you will get exception `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Prohibited package name: java.util`

Comment: I got the first point, that it's generally indeed possible and used to create patch. For the second part where some packages are "prohibited", do you have any reference/JLS section for that? It doesn't look so neat or standard.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming .JAR distribution, you can [seal the packages](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/sealman.html) by adding the following lines to `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`:

```
Name: myCompany/myPackage/
Sealed: true
```

A few notes:

- Each package requires its own entry.
- This doesn't prevent a crafty person from stripping out the lines from the manifest file and redistributing it internally. If this is a problem, you may need to look into some self validation techniques, such as enforcing the classes in sealed packages to check that the manifest has been left untouched.

Comment: This is new info to me. But what if I sabotage by distributing a jar of mine, and sealing other people's package there? E.g. `Name: org.apache Sealed: true`

Comment: @Charles, the system is far from perfect for that exact reason. I believe Java 9's module system is going to battle that particular issue but I haven't looked into it yet in such way that I could say for sure.